# Kia cee'd 2007 Aircon compressor

Tags: ac, kia, air-compressor

I've got a 2007 Kia cee'd 1.4L Petrol Hatchback and the air-con compressor seems to be busted.
I am having a look online and I can see quite a variety of compressor models both new and used going around. I am quite new to car repair so I was wondering if there are certain specifications that the compressor should meet or I could just buy and run of the mill kia cee'd compressor?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Just changing the compressor is not going to fix your A.C. Special tools are needed to evacuate and charge the system. Accumalator\drier may need replaced and pressure gages are necessary. Any A.C. work should be done by a shop equipped with the proper tools or Theresa good chance that all you do is put money into it and still have no A.C.

Comment: Thanks for you response Jupiter, I should have explained myself better. The plan is not for me to do the repair. I just want to provide the parts as KIA parts are quite hard to come by where I live (especially used) .